# Dropdown list selected item always set to default value

Tags: c#, asp.net

I wish to pass values of the selected items into a database and however noticed that the selected item is not what is sent into the database you can see in the snap shot below.
[image]
during run time the following value is recorded.
[image]

Where did it all go wrong with the dropdown lists selected item?
Counting on your intelligence...thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put your call to load the dropdownlist in

```
    if (!Page.IsPostBack)
    {
//LoadDropdownListHere();
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Try `DBNull.Value` instead of `null`.

Edit:

I think you need to specify the type using this overload: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc491445.aspx

```
CSMDataSource.InsertParameters.Add("CaseID", DBType.Int32, CaseIDDropDownList.SelectedItem.Text);
```

Comment: thanks Greg... but when i get the following error when i try DBNull.Value: (The best overload method match for "System.Web.UI.WebControls.ParameterCOllection.Add(String,String)" has some invalid arguments). Looks like that clearly does not fit the occasion unless am not using it well or missing some declaration

Comment: I gotta be honest here, I'm not familiar with the `SqlDataSource`.  I thought you were using `SqlDataAdapter`.  I have no idea what that's supposed to do.

Comment: thanks Greg...I had to change the entire insert parameters from datasources to parameters. was a hectic try but it worked out. i have edited the question to show just the second part of it. do you have any idea how i can solve this problem? the selected value from the dropdown list not being the one passed into the database. where could the problem be coming from?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem for the dropdownlist always selecting the first value. It appears the dropdown list is always rebinded anytime i click a button that requires a post pack as such the data tha was binded at page load re binds a gain before the selected item gets picked as such the default first value gets picked all the time. to solve my problem i first disabled enable auto postback on the dropdownlist and in the code behind that is my .cs file during the page load, where i first binded the data to the dropdown list, i used a condition like if(!ispostback) to bind my data. what this does is when the page loads first time the dropdownlist is binded and if i should select an item from the drop down list, the "auto post back" that i disabled earlier on keeps the selected item selected and when i click and button that requires a post to the server, the (!ispostback) prevents the dropdownlist to be binded again before selection. so in effect, the selection is done first and afterwards if the page should load anew, the drop down list is binded again.

i was in a bit of a rush while typing so please bare with my typo errors. do call in anytime for more clarification...peace